# RoundingMode HALF_EVEN analogous to the rounding policy used for float

Tags: java, rounding

The javadoc of RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN states:

> This rounding mode is analogous to the rounding policy used for float
>   and double arithmetic in Java.

What does this sentence exactly mean? 
I noticed only that only HALF_UP is used, e.g by String.format or Decimal format.

Comment: What is your question about exactly? [rounding modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking) in general? Or specific application of this rounding mode when working with BigDecimals?

Comment: The question is precisley about the posted sentences, neither Rounding modes, nor BigDecimals (already answered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic" (which Java numbers are modelled after) require intermediate results to use the max precision necessary and round to the result width at the end. The default rule for the rounding is HALF_EVEN.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules

Comment: To clarify, this is about the rounding out at the last bit of the internal representation (out at bit 53 for `double`) when doing calculations, and has nothing to do with the rounding applied for display.